# Executing jquery after a link has loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, href

Alright so I feel like I'll be sounding a bit confusing explaining this but Ill give it a shot. My site consists of two seperate webpages which ill call the main page and the menu page. At the top of each page exists a navigation bar with four options. The main page has several different areas which users can view which are shown via the nav bar and use of jquery show() and hide() functions. So basically someone clicks on the 'contact us' button everything else on the page is hidden and the contactUs div is shown. Ive set it up so that if you are on the menupage and click any of the nav links (except the one leading to the menupage) it will direct you to the root_url (which is the main page). What I cant figure out is how can I execute javascript or jquery after someone has clicked this link so that after being redirected to the main page I can show or hide the proper categories.

Sorry for any confusion!

```
function showContactUs(){
                    $("#contactUs").show();
                    $("#forms").hide();
                    $("#landlords").hide();
                    $("#apartments").hide();
                    $("#home").hide();
                    $("#aboutUs").hide();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the url itself, or perhaps a better option is to just add a class to the different HTML/PHP files you are redirecting to:

```
<body class="contactUs">
//or
<body class="aboutUs">
```

js

```
$("#"+$('body').attr('class')).show();
```

Comment: Im pretty unfamiliar with php would you know if theres a way to pass info via url using rails? Ive been poking around and it doesnt seem like it

Comment: It does'nt really matter what you serverside language is, what you need to do is pass something along that lets you identify the different pages, either something in the URL, or as above adding a class or element to the markup. Either way it has to be something that will be unique for each page sent from the server so that you can check it with javascript to see what page you are on and show the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter in the url then use that parameter to show/hide items on the other page.

http://chrismills.me/work/project-detail.php?project=knot

There's an example on my portfolio site, then search in functions.js file on my site for
// load featured project and that will show you how to display based on that parameter in the url.

Comment: Kind of missing where I can find a function.js file on your site any chance you could clarify?

Comment: sure it is http://chrismills.me/scripts/functions.js then find // load featured project